# Excel Solver with mixed-type variables .. esp Binary

Tags: excel, solver

I've been using Excel Solver and other related apps from Frontline Systems.  And, I'm a consultant for gigs that use these tools.  So, I think I know a bit about it.  Nonetheless, I'm trying to figure out what's going on here:
I'm doing an optimization where part of the task is to decide which variables are really useful.  So, I've constructed the "problem" to have the more typical LONG or DOUBLE numeric variables which are combined using various algorithms (whose "coefficients" may also be variables).  Then the algorithm results are combined with logic.  In the end, there is a single cell / a numeric value that is being maximized.
There are binary variables used in the logic to "turn on" and "turn off" the use of some pieces of the algorithms.
All this works fine up to a point and is at least "good enough" for most purposes.
But, I'm trying to understand better what I'm seeing.
There are maybe 10 binary variables being used as these "switches".  I can change their values manually and observe the outcome of the solver solutions.
I find that some of them aren't set to their optimum values.  So, I've written a short VBA sub to check them specifically and to change them if there's an improvement to be had  in the solution outcome.
I'm not asking "why" this happens because I'm using the Evolutionary method and I do understand that a global optimum isn't guaranteed.

But, I wonder if dealing with binary variables like this there isn't some better way to configure the Solver input to avoid writing augmenting code?  I can't imagine what that might be but maybe someone knows better.  In this cazse there are over 40 variables but only around 8 binary variables amongst them.